# Conditional format range of cells based on one cell matching another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Attached image for clarity (see below).

I've got a range of cells in need of conditional formatting. These cells represent our potential incoming weekly orders (cells E20:BA32). The first value in those columns is the number of the week within the year 2021 (see image). These orders come in 7 weeks after they are quoted.

I have another cell (BC1) containing the current week (in this case it is week 4 of 2021). This value is dynamic and will increment as time passes in 2021 (week 4 > 5 > 6 etc.)

I need to highlight a vertical slice of my orders that correspond to those that we are likely to receive 7 weeks down the road. In this case, I want to see the potential orders coming in at week 11 of 2021.

My current rule applies to the E20:BA32 range, and is the following (E5 was active cell when selecting the range):
=E$20=VALUE($BC1)+7

It seems to be properly highlighting week 11, but not the values (orders) beneath it that correspond to that week. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `$` sign. Update your formula to `=E$20=$BC$1+7`

Make sure you have the correct cells activated for your formula to work properly.

---

Explanation: The dollar sign in front of the `1` makes sure that even when the formula travels down to say, row 21, it still stays locked in row 1. Currently, every row that the formula goes down, the reference to `$BC1` increments a row as well.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid, thank you sir.

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be:

```
=E$20=$BC$1+7
```

Set your "applies to" range appropriately.